# SQL Server : create view by joining two tables and find sum of two columns in new column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

I have two tables `StockIn` and `StockOut`, identified by their Id number. Now I want to create a view to find the stock at hand where `StockIn.Id = StockOut.Id`.

This is my SQL code that I had been trying to but could not get the result:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[StockHand_Total] 
AS 
    SELECT 
        i.Id,
        i.ProductName,
        i.Rate,
        i.Qty,
        So.QtyOut,
        i.Amount,
        x.Balance
    FROM
        dbo.StockIn i 
    JOIN
        StockOut So ON i.Id = So.Id

    SELECT Balance = SUM(Qty - QtyOut)   
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[StockHand_Total] 
AS
    SELECT 
        i.Id,
        i.ProductName,
        i.Rate,
        i.Qty,
        So.QtyOut,
        i.Amount,
        Balance = SUM(COALESCE(i.Qty, 0) - COALESCE(so.QtyOut, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY i.id)
    FROM
        dbo.StockIn i 
    LEFT JOIN
        StockOut So ON i.Id = So.Id
```

Comment: it worked but I have another issue, it is showing only the records which are both in StockIn Table and in StockOut Table. But what I am looking for is even if the item is not in StockOut Table but in StockIn Table then the view table should show the item (Without balance or 0 balance is okay in this case). Could you help me with this?

Comment: @Turing LEFT JOIN

Comment: Partitioning by **primary key** looks redundant (I believe it's just a `ISNULL(i.QtyIn, 0) - ISNULL(so.QtyOut, 0 )`) and the OP is probably gonna  need a FULL JOIN in the end.

Comment: @ Lukasz Szozda my StockOut table will have multiple record with same Id, so can I use DISTINCT. If so can you guide me how to?